# How to run a macro using apex class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, macros

How can I run a macro using apex class? I have used a Visualforce Page to run the macro with standard method "sforce.console.runmacro" in javascript.  Similarly, I need to call it in an apex class instead. Is it possible? How?

Comment: this is helpful for you: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_selectmacro.htm

Comment: @sekhar, thanks for giving the response and  giving a link. i already saw that link and used in visual force page. i also mentioned in above description of my question. i need to call it in a apex class instead of visual force page.

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124358/initiate-service-cloud-console-macro-using-workflow-apex